# Call an API that collects all data and graphs in cells for a PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file where I want to print one pdf with multiple pages based on a drop-down list. It should be based on another cell with a value >0.
It works. I just want the daily report with one click instead of 100 clicks.

The name of the sheet is "PRINT" and the range "A1:I28" should be printed.
"B1" contains a list where I choose a department from a list of 16.
I get the lists I want to run for auto-print in "A1".
Objects in the list should only be printed when "I2" is ">0". (There are 2000 possibilities but only 10-30 each day that pass my ">0" value. Shown as a green dot if >0.)
PDF can be placed in the same folder as the Excel file. The name should be B2+I1.pdf (Department name and date).

When I change the value in "A1" today the file calls an API that collects all data and graphs in cells "A3:I28". Found a solution that printed my pdf's but didn't update the graphs.

Is it possible to solve this with VBA?

```vb
Sub PrintAll()
    Dim strValidationRange As String
    Dim rngValidation As Range
    Dim rngDepartment As Range
     
    ' Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    ' Identify the source list of the data validation
    strValidationRange = Range("B1").Validation.Formula1
    Set rngValidation = Range(strValidationRange)
     
    ' Set the value in the selection cell to each selection in turn
    ' and print the results.
    For Each rngDepartment In rngValidation.Cells
        Range("B1").Value = rngDepartment.Value
     
        Dim ThisFile As Variant
        ThisFile = Worksheets("PRINT").Range("B2").Value & " - " & _
          Worksheets("PRINT").Range("I1").Value & ".pdf"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
          Type:=xlTypePDF, _
          Filename:=ThisFile, _
          Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
          IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
          IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
          OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Final results in this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1shHpIFgtFoco6RIqbSv_xCIaUcwNZ5qG?usp=sharing)

I get "Name ID1" and "Name ID2" when I print manually - like it should.

When I run this macro it only updates the ID-number (A1) and tries to call the API. No graphs updated. Instead I get the "Calling Api"-pdf.

Comment: Sounds like you have a code attempt that you can [edit] your question with?

Comment: I had but started from zero again.

Comment: "one pdf with multiple sides" mean multiple pages? Add the async (you have to wait till loaded) API call to question. Also show code of that API-Call and the code how it is called (event) when you change the department. Tried a huge `.Wait` (e.g one minute)? Maybe better to first fetch all data (and store it somewhere) and then put it in sheet and print ( or copy sheet for each PDF needed and print them seperate you can delete them if no longer needed). Can you provide a sample file (without sensitive data!)?

Comment: Now it's multiple pages instead of side. That's not the big problem, actually don't now whats the easiest solution to work with in the end. I've tried .wait for 60 seconds but with the same result. I added a link with how it exports today and how I want it to export.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like all you want to do is update your graphs.

I would do this like that:

```
Sub UpdateGraphs()
Dim Graphs As ChartObject

For Each Graphs In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Graphs.Chart.Refresh
Next

End Sub
```

This will update all Graphs in the active Sheet when called.

Comment: Thanks,The graphs updates without problem from API when I use the excel, but I want the macro to print me a pdf with graphs ("Print" sheet  - Range "A1:I28") for all alternatives in the drop down list that match my "I2=>0"

Comment: You can just call This Sub from your Macro that Printed the PDF

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to work. When changing between the results in the drop down list "Department" turns to "..calling API". I think the macro need to pause for 3-4 seconds to call the API and update the graphs. I've tried "Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")" but it just not seems to be the right solution.

Comment: Code added to main question above.